# Recursive function pointers. Stroustrup's example

Tags: c++

Currently I'm reading Stroustrup Programming: Principles and Practice C++. I faced up with this example:

```
typedef void (*Pfct0)(struct Shape2*);
typedef void (*Pfct1int)(struct Shape2*,int);

struct Shape2{
    Pfct0 draw;
    Pfct1int rotate;
};

void draw(struct Shape2* p)
{
    (p->draw)(p);
}

void rotate(struct Shape2* p,int d)
{
    (p->rotate)(p,d);
}

int f(struct Shape2* pp)
{
    draw(pp);
    return 0;
}
```

I cannot get what functions draw and rotate actually do.
I know what is typedef, function pointer, -> operator.
As I understand p->draw function will call itself recursively. Am I right?
What practical uses of making such functions as draw or rotate?

Comment: No, they are not calling themselves recursively. They call the function that is contained in the draw and rotate fields of the struct.

Comment: There is no recursion here. The non-class functions simply call the class functions via pointers.

Comment: Could you please specify where are draw or rotate fields? I cannot get. Or maybe could you put some reference to sample code, where I could read about similar issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions `draw` and `rotate` calls a functions pointed to by members of structure `p`, and call these functions on a pointer to this structure `p`.

maybe this will help:

```
typedef void (*pointer_to_function)(struct Shape2*);

struct Shape2{
    pointer_to_function draw;
    Pfct1int rotate;
};

void function(struct Shape2* p)
{
    (p->draw)(p);
    ^^^^^^^^^
    // this is pointer_to_function so call the function pointed to by it 
    // with some argument of type struct Shape2*, in example p itself, why not
}
```

The misleading in this snippet is that we don't see how pointers in objects Shape2 are initialized, but they must be initialized to point to some functions with appropriate signatures before they are passed to global `draw` and `rotate`.

Comment: So when one creates a Shape2 object, one has to create methods for it?

Answer (score 2):

It appears to me that Stroustrup is implementing object-like dispatch in pure C.  Each Shape2 object has its own draw and rotate methods.  Given an arbitrary Shape2 p, draw(p) looks up that p's draw method, and applies it to itself (presumably p would have some other content that draw would read and take action upon.)  The function does not call itself recursively unless the particular draw function for p calls draw recursively.  This is very much like what p.draw() would do in C++ if Shape2 were a base class.

Answer (score 1):

Each instance of `Shape2` can have its own draw and rotate functions.

If `s` is a pointer to a `Shape`,

```
draw(s);
```

is the same as

```
(s->draw)(s);
```

This could be used to implement something like

```
drawrect(Shape* s);
drawcircle(Shape* s);
...
Shape shapes[2];
shapes[0].draw = &drawrect;
shapes[1].draw = &drawcircle;
...
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    draw(&shapes[i]);
}
```